# iPhone App User Login Authentication with Server

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, rest, authentication

What steps would I have to take to create a database server that would allow a user to create an account that would hold their progress in the app? Basically I want users to be able to login and start where they left off last time they opened the app. I'm not sure how to get the server or if I could just use core data. I know this question is pretty brief, i just need a place to start, like a book or an example. Thanks!

Comment: Do you even need a server side service?  Would a local database on the device work or do they need to access from many devices to that data?  Also, is the data shared (many users interact on it) or is it per user (like documents)?

Comment: I wanted it to be an educational thing. So a teacher would be the main user... but would have their class of student users that will login and do lessons and whatnot. So the data would just be progress, like level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends quite a bit on the scope of your application.  In my current experience using Microsoft's .Net MVC 4 framework is the way to go.  It allows you to create a RESTful web api that you can then use an iOS framework like RESTkit or AFNetworking to access and transfer data in the format that you prefer (json, xml, text).  You can then write your data from the web api controller to your back-end db.  It's a good recipe for creating enterprise iOS apps. Also - check out objection if you use the repository pattern of development, it's a nice addition to writing apps that follow MVC - iOS or not.

Check out the web api tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api